# Custom 404-Not Found page on Repl.it

Tags: javascript, html, css, http-status-code-404, replit

How can I create my custom 404-not found page for a website I created through [Repl.it](https://www.repl.it)? I know I would have to go to the `.htaccess` file if *I* were hosting it (or using a hosting service, maybe?), but what about through Repl.it? How can I create my custom 404-not found page using HTML, Javascript, and CSS?

Note: I already have the file written as a `.html`. I just need to be able to display it on an invalid URL...

Comment: Looks like you're gonna need to [set up a Rails server](https://repl.it/talk/ask/custom-404-error/9996).

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through **repl.it** specs and for
now  if you want to add custom error pages. 
You have to use python or next.js or any backend language .

And for server configuration using htaccess or nginx. Answer is already given by matthew above.

Comment: Please be specific! How, exactly, do I do this?

Comment: go through this link https://repl.it/@kognise .  he has created many website using different languages. i hope you can find useful .

Comment: and this repl https://fontkey.kognise.repl.co/  has custom 404 page. you can find the code in above link i given you .

Comment: +1 now, b/c this could be helpful. But I won't give this a check because it doesn't directly answer my question. I'll have to read through all this code to find it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how Repl.it works but I can tell you how to redirect on 404 errors in Apache and Nginx webservers - if you have access to edit the respective config file.

In Apache, which I think you are using, in `.htaccess` add the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /your-404-page.html
```

for Nginx webserver, you'd need to find the config file which is usually found in `nginx/sites-available/your-site.com` and then add the following

```
error_page 404 /your-404-page.html;
```